# What extension would you suggest for Visual Studio Code to make development easier?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, js, app-development

So I've been working on a project where are lots of lwc component and it's now hard to quickly understand where one component change data and pass it to another one. Are there any good ways or extensions to show where variables are used between all components? Also, what extensions you use to make development easier?

Comment: [Codefriar's pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=codefriar.codefriar-s-pack) has a lot of great stuff, especially Tabnine, AI-driven auto-completion is epic.

Comment: I've just +1'ed this to get it back to zero as its hard for any of us to keep up with extensions and a good suggestion may come from this question. Also, lots of no-comment downvotes here lately and I think [We are not Reddit or Stack Overflow](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3155/we-are-not-reddit-or-stack-overflow) is worth reading and thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

For all forms of Salesforce development within Vs Code i recommend the Salesforce Extension Pack (Extended).